# Practical uses of inclusive start conditions in scanner generator

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

What are some real-world (not-contrived) lexical-scanning problems where "inclusive scan conditions" (as opposed to "exclusive" ones) are a better solution?

That is, when is `%s FOO` any better than `%x FOO` in a (f)lex definition?

I understand the difference in function as well as how to implement the difference in a scanner generator. I'm just trying to get a sense of the kinds of situations where you would legitimately want to mash together different groups of scan rules into a single scan condition.

Full disclosure: Answers will inspire example code for [this project](https://github.com/kjosib/booze-tools/).

Answer (score 1):

"Mashing together" lexical rules is pretty common. Consider backslash-escape handling, which you might want to do more or less the same way in different quoting syntaxes and even regex literals. But those are likely to be combined explicitly.

For an only slightly contrived example of where implicit combination with the INITIAL state might be used, consider lexical analysis of a Python-like language with contextually meaningful leading whitespace. Here, there are two almost-identical lexical contexts: the normal context, in which a newline character is a syntactic marker and leading whitespace needs to be turned into INDENT/DEDENT sequences, and the parenthesised context in which newlines and leading whitespace are both just whitespace, which is not forwarded to the parser. These contexts will only differ in a couple of patterns; the vast majority of rules will be shared. So having an inclusive state which contains only something like:

```
<IN_PAREN>[[:space:]]+  /* Ignore all whitespace */
```

might be a simple solution. Of course, that rule would have to be placed before normal whitespace handling so that it overrides while `IN_PAREN` is active.